# Is there a way to detect whether #pragma unmanaged is in effect in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a project that includes some performance sensitive native C++ headers making heavy use of templates.  For this project we also wrap the headers and add some glue code to expose the functionality to c# and other .NET languages.  We'll call this header "layout.h", and we'll assume it's a third party header that I can't change.

In a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly it is relatively easy to make a mistake and #include  from a place in the code where #pragma unmanaged (or #pramga managed(push,off) ) .  When that happens the templates generate IL, and I get extra managed/unmanaged transitions when running the code and performance goes down the drain.

My question is whether there is a way I can do a compile-time check just before the #include so that compilation fails if I am accidently #including from the wrong context.

```
// File1.cpp, compiled in a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly with /clr
    ASSERT_UNMANAGED()
    #include <layout.h>
```

My naive 1st attempt checked #ifdef _MANAGED, but that is always defined whether I'm in a #pragma unmanaged block of code or not.

Comment: This is a really tough one. I can think of a dozen different ways to implement `ASSERT_MANAGED`, but `ASSERT_UNMANAGED` has me stumped.

Comment: just in case someone what to look up,  _MANAGED, __CLR_VER, and __cplusplus_cli are unaffected by #pragma managed/ #pragma ummanaged, there scopes are the entire compile unit.

Answer (score 2):

The pragma directives must be inserted directly in the include file. In this way, everywhere you include the file an unmanaged section is declared.

Sorry that  you have to modify your include file.

Answer (score 0):

You may write `ASSERT_MANAGED` or `ASSERT_UNMANAGED` code that would use construct that is available ONLY while compiling managed or unmanaged. A `ref class` declaration is an example which is avaiable only when using managed.

This is somewhat a dirty solution, but it would work.

Comment: So ref class declarations -do- work when writing an ASSERT_MANAGED().  The trick is to find legal C++ that is not legal C++/CLI to enable writing the ASSERT_UNMANAGED() block

Comment: Another nearest competitor is using constant string concatenation, if it works it is CLI code (System::String), otherwise it is native code. I am still probing more into it!

Comment: I thought of void __fastcall foo();  Doesn't actually work, bit of a compiler bug there.

Comment: Did you ever find a valid implementation for ASSERT_UNMANAGED()?  I have found a need for something similar...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, making use of the fact that intrinsics are always compiled as native (unmanaged) code:

```
#include <intrin.h>

#define ASSERT_UNMANAGED() \
int TestFunc(void) { \
    __pragma(warning(push)) \
    __pragma(warning(error:4793)) \
    auto aumt = [] () { return _bextr_u64(65537, 0, 8); }; \
    __pragma(warning(pop)) \
    return int(aumt()); }

#pragma unmanaged   // Comment out this line and the assertion fails!
ASSERT_UNMANAGED()
#pragma managed
```

EDIT: Of course, if you just want warnings rather than compilation failure, you can remove the 3 `__pragma(warning())` lines.